# Sort by inner row of PHP array

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array with the following structure:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < SOME_NUMBER; $i++) {
   $arr[$i][] = $info_1;
   $arr[$i][] = $info_2;
   $arr[$i][] = $info_3;
   $arr[$i][] = $DATE;
   $arr[$i][] = $info_4;
}
```

I need this array to be sorted by `$DATE`. Now i can not change the structure of the array, i cant change keys. Is it possible to sort `$arr` with `$DATE`

Example:

```
 after running the loop for 2 times $arr is equal to:

 $arr[0][0] = 'Some Info 1.1';
 $arr[0][1] = 'Some Info 1.2';
 $arr[0][2] = 'Some Info 1.3';
 $arr[0][3] = '05-08-2010';
 $arr[0][4] = 'Some Info 1.4';

 $arr[1][0] = 'Some Info 2.1';
 $arr[1][1] = 'Some Info 2.2';
 $arr[1][2] = 'Some Info 2.3';
 $arr[1][3] = '01-08-2011';
 $arr[1][4] = 'Some Info 2.4';
```

the expected output would be:

```
 $arr[0][0] = 'Some Info 2.1';
 $arr[0][1] = 'Some Info 2.2';
 $arr[0][2] = 'Some Info 2.3';
 $arr[0][3] = '01-08-2011';
 $arr[0][4] = 'Some Info 2.4';

 $arr[1][0] = 'Some Info 1.1';
 $arr[1][1] = 'Some Info 1.2';
 $arr[1][2] = 'Some Info 1.3';
 $arr[1][3] = '05-08-2010';
 $arr[1][4] = 'Some Info 1.4';
```

using `array_sort` didnt work.

Comment: nvm i dont know why i wrote array_keys, i meant array_sort

Comment: Even so, stack is about helping you with your code not writing it for you; you have not shown us what you've tried that failed.  'using array_sort' does not tell us what you did, only that you used a function somehow.  Edit your question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting on the fourth index of each array item, based on a `strtotime()` comparison:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a[3]) - strtotime($b[3]);
});
```

Comment: That was Brilliant! Wish I could +5 rather than +1

Answer (score 2):

You should use php function `usort()` that sorts an array using a custom function. Here is how to do it at a glance.

**Initialize your array:**

```
 $arr[0][0] = 'Some Info 1.1';
 $arr[0][1] = 'Some Info 1.2';
 $arr[0][2] = 'Some Info 1.3';
 $arr[0][3] = '05-08-2010';
 $arr[0][4] = 'Some Info 1.4';

 $arr[1][0] = 'Some Info 2.1';
 $arr[1][1] = 'Some Info 2.2';
 $arr[1][2] = 'Some Info 2.3';
 $arr[1][3] = '01-08-2011';
 $arr[1][4] = 'Some Info 2.4';
```

**Declare the comparison function that compares the two dates:**

```
function cmp($a,$b){
 $d1 = date_parse($a[3]);
 $d2 = date_parse($b[3]);
 return  ($d1 < $d2) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

**and finally call `usort()` using your comparison function.**

```
usort($arr,"cmp");
```

Please note that the mentioned comparison function assumes that the date is always at the **3rd** index. If you want more flexibility, customize the comparison function to find the date index before the actual comparison. Good luck!

---

### More info:

- [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [date_parse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)